# Servers mail don't receive email with attachment successfully using headers mail() php

Tags: php, email

That's my first question, I hope someone can help me with my problem. =( =( =(

I want to send a e-mail with zip attachment using mail() php.

I have this code:

```
$file = $path.$filename;
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
$uid= md5(uniqid(time()));
$bound="--".$uid."\r\n";
$last_bound="--".$uid."--\r\n";
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= $bound;
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$body .= $message."\r\n";
$body .= $bound;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/zip; name=\"".$file."\"\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$body .= $content."\r\n";
$body .= $last_bound;

mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $header)
```

The result is:

Gmail receives the email with files inside the zip.

Hotmail receives the email without files inside the zip.

Private mail server receives the email without attachment, only a huge string.

How can I modify this code to send attachment and all mail servers successfully receive the e-mail?

Thanks, best regards!

Comment: What is your private mail server? can it handle attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using...
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"

instead of...
Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8

It's been a while since I have messed with PHP and mail but I prefer using a library which has already figured out a lot of these issues... a classic being:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
or 
http://swiftmailer.org/